# Set all the 0 values to NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can I set all the 0 values to NULL in an SQL table ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So which is it? Set NULL value to 0, or set 0 values to NULL?

Comment: Title and body are opposite questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
update table set col = null where col = 0
```

Comment: it's not usable because if I have more than for example 30 column what can I do?Am I write all of the columns name.??

Comment: @Nuisance if you need to update 30 columns to null, when they are zero, you will have to write the code for that like shown above. Why isn't that usable ?

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYCOLUMN = NULL WHERE MYCOLUMN = 0
```

But do you mean in all columns? That will be more work and best you just create separate statements for each column. It is also possible to read the schema and generate an SQL in a stored procedure and EXEC that but I do not recommend since I imagine this is a one-off job and if you are doing this more often then something with the design is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Col1 = NULLIF(Col1, 0),
    Col2 = NULLIF(Col2, 0),
    Col3 = NULLIF(Col3, 0)
WHERE (Col1 = 0 
    OR Col2 = 0 
    OR Col3 = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a one time job, you could always grab the output from following statement and execute that.

```
SELECT  'UPDATE ' 
        + OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID)
        + ' SET '
        + sc.name
        + ' = NULL WHERE '
        + sc.name
        + ' = 0'        
FROM    sys.columns sc 
        INNER JOIN sys.types st ON st.system_type_id = sc.system_type_id
WHERE   st.name IN ('bigint', 'int', 'smallint')        
        AND OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = 'YourTable'
```