# can't add NOT NULL constraint

Tags: mysql

I have a table called Person in MySQL. There is a column called `username`. I want to add `NOT NULL` constraint to this column using the following:

```
ALTER TABLE Person MODIFY username VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL;
```

But it failed and reported error as:

```
Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'username' at row 1
```

Why can't I change this column to be NOT NULL?

Comment: Just wondering: is the table already populated and has some `NULL` values in column username?

Comment: Is it currently VARCHAR(32) and not something like VARCHAR(100)?

Comment: Yes, it is populated and has some NULL values in that column.

Comment: There *are* NULL values in the columns, then 1) *delete* the records that conflict with "NOT NULL" or; 2) assign a non-NULL value. In SQL Server one can also supply a DEFAULT VALUE (that will be used in place of current columns with NULL); not sure if MySQL supports the same when altering a column. (This is about the 2nd error reported, not the first.)

Comment: What do you want the `NULL` values to be instead then? You're telling it that column cannot be `NULL`, but it already is. ** This is where you take a backup of the database ** Just guessing, but I'd look to setting a default value for the column, either before the modifying-it-to-`NOT NULL` or in the same statement.

Answer (score 11):

Is it possible that you already have NULL values for username stored in your table? Then you would get an error as you are creating an inconsistency within your table.

Comment: Yes, I already have some NULL values in that column. So how do I change to NOT NULL in that case?

Comment: You will have to change all the NULL values in that column to something that is not NULL.  Otherwise, you'd have NULLs in a column that is defined as NOT NULL.

Comment: You should run an update-query to change all NULL values to a default value that is not NULL. Then you may alter your column.
You should always keep in mind that consistency is a key concept in databases. Your database should and will enforce this concept which is a good sign. Therefore, always check if changing your schema is consistent with your data. Act if inconsistencies emerge. Depending on the circumstances you need to either reconsider your schema changes or transform your data.

Comment: If you just need a query that changes your null values, go from **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245475/set-all-the-null-values-to-0)** you just need to insert your table, column and the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you make your column length smaller. From an unknown value to 32 characters. The first row contains more than 32 characters in your `username` column. That would lead to data loss if you change the table that way.

You can find the records with `username`s greater 32 characters with this query

```
select * from person
where length(username) > 32
```

Comment: Yes, I've changed it to VARCHAR(32). But I still got a different error: `Error Code: 1138. Invalid use of NULL value`.

Comment: Do you have null values in your username column?

Comment: Yes, I have some null values in username column. How do I add NOT NULL constraint when there are some NULL values in that column? Is it possible?

Comment: @tonga: No that is not possible. Either fill the data in that `null` entries or allow `null`s.